# How to use unused space in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive

I installed ubuntu on my machine with only 80 GB of memory anticipating that I will remove it later but now I want to keep it forever (until I am frustrated with linux). I have 500 GB in my machine and now I want to use that raw 420 GB of space. How I can I do that ?

with "space/memory" I am referring to secondary memory not Ram.

Here is output of :

> sudo fdisk -l
>
> Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes 255 heads, 63
>   sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x000dcb77
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>   /dev/sda1   *        2048   136718335    68358144   83  Linux

Comment: can you please post the output of `sudo fdisk -l`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

open your terminal and type this

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Then type as

```
gksudo gparted
```

then you can find your space over there and you can create partitions .

Comment: Well..I cannot access this newly created partition neither I can update permissions

Comment: There is a limit of creating primary partitions . so how many you did ?

Comment: I just created only one partition the way you said. Do I need to specify something else ?

Comment: No just you need to mention what type it is . 

try again . select It click at New and format to your required type .

Comment: should I create as extended partition ?

Comment: still getting the same problem.

Comment: Ok ravi see this guide once http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html

Answer (score 3):

Boot with LiveCD and adjust the size of your Ubuntu partition with [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) as you wish, which is pretty intuitive to use:
[image]

PS: If you boot with your installed Ubuntu, you could not adjust the partition size since it is already mounted.

Answer (score 3):

You currently have 1 partition sda1 with your entire Linux system on it.

You have two options:

1) Extend your existing partition.

To make your current system use the disks entire space you will have to use a Live CD to boot your system and then modify your partition to take up the rest of the available space.

GParted is a good Live CD available [here](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php).

Insert the CD, reboot your system using the Live CD, and follow [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted) tutorial it will show exactly how to resize the partition using gparted.

2)Alternativly you can add an additional partition.

You can add an additional partition to the disk, the second partition can take up the remaining space this can then be mounted somewhere on your filesystem like `/var/morespace/` this will let you use this for storage.