# How do I Merge Partitions to use Unused Available HD space in Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

Is this even possible, or am I mixing terminologies?

First, consider the results of `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL`

```
NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sr0            1024M            
sda            74.5G            
├─sda1 ext4    46.8G            
├─sda2            1K            
├─sda5 swap     3.1G [SWAP]     
└─sda6 ext4    24.7G /
```

I had a laptop given to me, and without too much foresight, I only allocated 25GB for my Ubuntu instance. Now I want to engulf the other partition on `sda1 ext 4` and preserve all my data and instance on `sda6 ext4`. The only way I can think of describing this is a partition merge.

Some have suggested [Gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229665/how-to-use-unused-space-in-ubuntu), but I am not sure how to do this without botoxing everything on my machine. Any suggestions?

**Update:**

I have tried resizing `sda1 ext4` from about 50GB to 25GB (the minimum amount), and now I have 22GB of unallocated space. I am unable to resize `sda6 ext4` in Gparted. Any idea how to use that unallocated space for expanding `sda6 ext4`?

Comment: sda1 is not a windows partition -- it says it's an ext4 filesystem, which is for linux, not windows.

Comment: Because of partition location, merge is very difficult. Your choices are a full backup and reinstall, restore backup, move /home to new partition, or use partition as a data partition and link folders back into /home. Multiple threads on each of those options, which would you prefer and we can suggest threads with details.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a merge; and anyway, you have sda5 (swap) in between these two. You would have to copy your data from sda6 to sda1, remove sda2-6, expand sda1 & add a new swap partition. Assuming you have space on sda1, otherwise you may need a second (USB?) drive.

That said, it is generally recommended to have at least a 3rd partition for /home as well, so you should end up with /sda1 (system folders), sda2 (user data - /home), & sda3 (swap) with sda2 being the larger.

A backup is obviously a good idea first!

You haven't said how much free space exists, nor if sda5/6 are logical partitions; assuming you have enough room, and that sda1 is not full, and 5/6 are logical (not physical) partitions. This wants doing as a live CD ideally, or you'll need a reboot halfway when your home folder moves:

Run `sudo gparted` & shrink sda1 to 20G; remove sda5 (swap) & make a new one, the full space between sda2 & sda6; you may be stuck with sda2 if it's in logical partitions. Format this new sda3 to ext4;  quit gparted at this point, mount sda3 & sda6, and copy the contents of sda6 to the new sda3 like this:

`shopt -s dotglob; cp sda6/* sda3`  - replacing the drives with where they are mounted. This ensures all the hidden files get included.

Then, back to gparted & remove sda6, expand sda3 to max-3Gb, make a new swap partition as sda4, activate it, have sda3 mounted at /home; & you're done.